# Delimiting single quote in BASH script from a SQL dump

Tags: bash

I am scrubbing a SQL dump file from MYSQL so that it is free of user information.  The file is 100s of megs in size, and I have it all working except for the SQL quotes.  I go line by line through the file and then use the statements in the form of:

```
RESULT=echo $LINE | sed "<something>"
```

This worked great until I came across this line:

```
INSERT INTO `brand` VALUES (42,84,'','brands/large_logo/L\'OrealLogo.jpg',0);
```

When I echo the line, the result is that I lose the L\'Oreal delimiter, and when I try to when load it back via SQL, it get an error.  Here's the lined via echo $LINE:

```
                                     The problem is here  v
 INSERT INTO `brand` VALUES (42,84,'','brands/large_logo/L'OrealLogo.jpg',0);
```

Is there a way to keep echo from using the \' as an escape sequence for '?  I feel like I am missing something obvious here, but just cannot get my finger on it.

Comment: `printf %q "str" ` is a great way of getting the proper quoting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Psychic debugging suggests that you are using a while read loop, but not suppling `-r`:

```
$ cat file
'Notice the \' here'

$ while read LINE; do echo "$LINE"; done < file
'Notice the ' here'

$ while read -r LINE; do echo "$LINE"; done < file
'Notice the \' here'
```

There are other concerns like missing `$(..)` and quoting in your `RESULT=echo $LINE | sed "<something>"` and the fact that you're running `sed` once for each line rather than for the stream, but these are separate issues.

Comment: It's probably not the issue here, but some versions of `echo` will also try to interpret escape sequences. If you want the variable printed without mangling, use `printf "%s\n" "$LINE"` instead of `echo`.